# Changing color of Drawer in MUI v5

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm using MUI v5 in my project and trying to apply styling to a `Drawer` so that the background color is black. Since this update was pretty recent I can't find much info on changing the styling of the component without using deprecated elements from MUI v4. Any tips for this? I would also appreciate some advice on applying a color that I've defined using `createTheme` from MUI as well.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Divider,
  Drawer,
  ListItem,
  ListItemButton,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
} from "@mui/material";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import qdjLogo from "../../assets/qdj_logo.png";
import "./styling/SideBarStyling.css";
import ProfileFooter from "./ProfileFooter";

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" anchor="left">
        <div className={"wrapper"}>
          <a href="">
            <img className={"icon"} src={qdjLogo} alt="QDJ Logo" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <ProfileFooter />
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply override the theme like this:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDrawer: {
      styleOverrides: {
        paper: {
          background: "orange"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/temporarydrawer-material-demo-forked-qlcye?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 7):

You can change the background color of the `Drawer` by styling the `Paper` component inside it using the [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) prop:

```
<Drawer
  PaperProps={{
    sx: {
      backgroundColor: "pink"
    }
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

If you want to set the `background-color` to black, maybe you want a dark theme? You can configure MUI theme to automatically set the dark background for `Paper` by setting the [dark mode](https://mui.com/customization/dark-mode/#main-content) like this:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark"
  }
});
```

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Content />
</ThemeProvider>
```

### Reference

- https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-from-jss

Answer (score 0):

If you change the color of Paper to change the background, you may not be able to pull down the drawer when you touch it.

Another way is changing backdrop props.

```
<Drawer
  anchor="bottom"
  open={open}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  slotProps={{
    backdrop: {
      sx: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255 255 255 / 50%)',
      }
    }
  }}
>
  <YourComponent />
</Drawer>
```